# Only able to remote desktop into Azure Windows 10 only once

Tags: windows-10, azure-virtual-machine, remote-desktop

I have a situation where, after upgrading to the most recent version of Windows 10, I'm only able to log into my Azure VM once. After I log in the first time, if my connection drops for whatever reason (which it's liable to do as my connection here is very unreliable) then I can't reconnect. I have to reboot the machine. I'm able to get past the login, however when I'm on the welcome screen it freezes and then I'm unable to do anything.

After a reboot, I can then connect successfully again until the connection drops, and then I have to reboot the machine.

The Windows version is "Windows 10 Pro N", build is 10.0.18362.

Previous to the upgrade I was able to connect multiple times with no issues.

Does anybody have any ideas what I could look for?

Thanks very much in advance,
Dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, I suggest installing the latest hotfix on https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/4517389/windows-10-update-kb4517389

Or [resize your Azure VM](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/resize-virtual-machines/).

Hope this could help you.

Comment: Heyo, thanks. I had the latest update installed and that hadn't fixed it. However resizing the VM does appear to have resolved it. Thanks again.